# Realm copyToRealmOrUpdate managed proxy giving error "This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable"?

Tags: android, realm

I am trying to use `copyToRealmOrUpdate` because i want to get back `managed proxy` of the `List`. But when i am trying to update the `List item` at a particular `index`, i am getting `error`

```
tranlist.get(0).setExercise("New Exercise");
```

> This Realm instance has already been closed, making it unusable

```
List<transactiondata> updatedlist;
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
     @Override
     public void execute(final Realm bgRealm) {
          tranlist = bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(updatedlist);                       
     }
}, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
     @Override
     public void onSuccess() {
          // Transaction was a success.
     }
}, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
     @Override
     public void onError(Throwable error) {
          // Transaction failed and was automatically cancelled.
     }
});
```

Can anyone please tell me why using this `managed proxy` i am getting the `error`.

**Update**

Now i am using addChangeListener

```
realm_list = realm.where(transactiondata.class).findAllAsync();
realm_list.addChangeListener(new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<transactiondata>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<transactiondata> transactiondata) {
            tranlist = transactiondata;
        }
    });
```

Now when i am trying to update `tranlist` at a particular position then changes are not persisting in `RealmDb`

```
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(final Realm bgRealm) {
            tranlist.get(0).setExercise("New Exercise");
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnSuccess() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // Transaction was a success.
        }
    }, new Realm.Transaction.OnError() {
        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            // Transaction failed and was automatically cancelled.
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your update should crash saying `"java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot modify managed objects outside of a write transaction."` unless it is done in `realm.executeTransaction()`

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Sorry, i was using `executeTransactionAsync` but still, changes are not persisting in `RealmDb`.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Also i am doing `tranlist = transactiondata;` in `addchangelistener` because i have a global `tranlist` list variable.

Answer (score 1):

Simple,

```
realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.executeTransactionAsync(new Realm.Transaction() {
     @Override
     public void execute(final Realm bgRealm) {
          tranlist = bgRealm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(tranlist); // <--
```

You're trying to get the List from the background thread directly, using the background thread Realm.

That Realm is opened to execute the transaction, commit the transaction, then is closed. So when you try to access the list on the UI thread, the background thread Realm has already been closed.

Considering you're trying to pass managed RealmObjects in this list to the UI thread, even if the Realm wasn't closed, you'd be getting `IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Managed RealmObjects can only be accessed on the thread where they were created`.

So instead of trying to get a managed proxy list from a background thread, you should be defining a query and listen for changes with that.

```
Realm realm;
RealmResults<transactiondata> results;
RealmChangeListener realmChangeListener = new RealmChangeListener() { ...

public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    ...
    results = realm.where(...).sort(...).findAllAsync();
    results.addChangeListener(realmChangeListener);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    ...
    results.removeAllChangeListeners();
    results = null;
    realm.close();
}
```

And I've just noticed - if you want to modify the property of the object, then if it weren't for the closed Realm and the illegal thread access, you'd also need to wrap it in a write transaction anyways.

```
final long id = tran.getId();
realm.executeTransactionAsync((bgRealm) -> {
    transactiondata bgTran = bgRealm.where(transactiondata.class).equalTo("id", id).findFirst();
    if(bgTran != null) {
        bgTran.setExercise("New exercise");
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please check my Updated post, Also thanks for helping me :)

Comment: Are you there ?? Please help me.

Comment: Now if you logged the throwable in onError(), you'd see `IllegalStateException: Realm access from incorrect thread. Managed RealmObjects can only be accessed on the thread where they were created` because you didn't follow the end of my post :P

Comment: But i guess `execute` method of `executeTransactionAsync` runs on the `UI thread` so why when i am trying to update list item there I am getting this Error ??

Comment: Are you there ??

Comment: As i am initialising my `tranlist` in `onChange` of `addChangeListener`, which is in UI thread and after that, i am updating the list item in `execute` of `executeTransactionAsync` which also runs in UI thread, then why i am getting this error, As both threads are UI ?? **Please help me** i am still stuck on this.

Comment: I think you need to update your code to reflect what you actually have at the moment.